# OpenXML with C#: replacing bookmark with HTML content

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using OpenXML to replace bookmarks in a docx file with text. I am able to do this but with plain text only. If I replace it with HTML, the document shows raw HTML instead of formatted document.
Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void ReplaceBookmarkText(WordprocessingDocument doc,
            string bookmarkName, string replacementText)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
            XElement bookmark = xDoc.Descendants(W.bookmarkStart)
                .FirstOrDefault(d =>
                    (string)d.Attribute(W.name) == bookmarkName);
            if (bookmark == null)
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Document doesn't contain bookmark.");
            if (bookmark.Parent.Name.Namespace == M.m)
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Replacing text in math formulas is not supported.");
            if (RevisionAccepter.HasTrackedRevisions(doc))
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
    "Replacing bookmark text in documents that have tracked revisions is not supported.");
            if (xDoc.Descendants(W.sdt).Any())
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
    "Replacing bookmark text in documents that have content controls is not supported.");
            XElement newRoot = (XElement)FlattenParagraphsTransform(xDoc.Root);
            XElement startBookmarkElement = newRoot.Descendants(W.bookmarkStart)
                .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute(W.name) == bookmarkName)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            int bookmarkId = (int)startBookmarkElement.Attribute(W.id);
            XElement endBookmarkElement = newRoot.Descendants(W.bookmarkEnd)
                .Where(d => (int)d.Attribute(W.id) == bookmarkId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (startBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.hyperlink).Any() ||
                endBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.hyperlink).Any())
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Bookmark is within a hyperlink.  Can't replace text.");
            if (startBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.fldSimple).Any() ||
                endBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.fldSimple).Any())
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Bookmark is within a simple field.  Can't replace text.");
            if (startBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.smartTag).Any() ||
                endBookmarkElement.Ancestors(W.smartTag).Any())
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Bookmark is within a smart tag.  Can't replace text.");
            if (startBookmarkElement.Parent != endBookmarkElement.Parent)
                throw new BookmarkReplacerException(
                    "Bookmark start and end not at same levels.  Can't replace text.");

            XElement parentElement = startBookmarkElement.Parent;
            var elementsBetweenBookmarks = startBookmarkElement
                .ElementsAfterSelf()
                .TakeWhile(e => e != endBookmarkElement);
            var newElements = parentElement
                .Elements()
                .TakeWhile(e => e != startBookmarkElement)
                .Concat(new[]
                {
                    startBookmarkElement,
                    new XElement(BookmarkReplacerCustomNamespace + "Insert",
                        elementsBetweenBookmarks
                            .Where(e => e.Name == W.r)
                            .Take(1)
                            .Elements(W.rPr)
                            .FirstOrDefault()),
                })
                .Concat(elementsBetweenBookmarks.Where(e => e.Name != W.p &&
                    e.Name != W.r && e.Name != W.tbl))
                .Concat(new[]
                {
                    endBookmarkElement
                })
                .Concat(endBookmarkElement.ElementsAfterSelf());
            parentElement.ReplaceNodes(newElements);

            newRoot = (XElement)UnflattenParagraphsTransform(newRoot);
            newRoot = (XElement)ReplaceInsertElement(newRoot, replacementText);
            newRoot = (XElement)DemoteRunChildrenOfBodyTransform(newRoot);

            xDoc.Elements().First().ReplaceWith(newRoot);
            doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
        }
```

Tried the code above but it only works with plain text. I am trying to replace bookmark text in a word document with HTML.